# TeamViewer sign in working on Macs, “Sign in request failed! The server did not respond. Please try again.”

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, teamviewer

I used TeamViewer on multiple computers and have no problems except with one of my Macs. I cannot log into the “Computers and Contacts” panel on the right side. When I try it spins for a while and I get the error:

> Sign in request failed! The server did not respond. Please try again.

I opened a ticket with TeamViewer and they really haven’t been able to help at all. They seem to think I am behind some sort of proxy or have antivirus/firewall running but I work in technology and know enough to say there is nothing blocking internet access on this system.

Sometimes logging into another user account fixes it temporarily. Just tonight I did a re-installation of Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite) and it worked initially but then it stops working and I am stuck.

Comment: Open TeamViewer, at the top Click on 'Extras'...from the drop down menu Click 'Options'...'Most popular options' should be listed at the Top...At the bottom is 'Connection in local network(via IP address); Incoming LAN connections should be 'deactivated'...Try that and see